# Error while compiling the main CPP containing self generated class

Tags: c++, class

I am compiling a program which includes the header file of the class that I created but the compiler shows an error
Build failed: undefined reference to my class::myclass.
I almost exactly written the code which I saw in a tutorial but it doesn't works out.

Comment: When you're following a tutorial, start with *exactly* the code in the tutorial. Leave experimentation for later. Also, [books are good for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Now I copied the exact code from the tutorial but it's still showing the same errori also noticed that the person in the tutorial uses a different version of code blocks from the version that I use.